# Filter records between particular hours minutes and seconds in Spark data frames

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a data frame

`+--------------------+---------------+------+
 |           timestamp| login         | Age  |
 +--------------------+---------------+------+
 2016-06-01 01:05:20  |        7372   |    50|
 2016-06-01 01:00:20  |        7374   |    35|
 2016-06-01 01:10:20  |        7376   |    40|`

I want records only between 1 to 1:10 time irrespective of date and

the time is in unix_timestamp as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

How to extract those records?
This is to analyze people who are coming late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved it using below code:

```
val attendenceDF = DF.withColumn("Attendence",when(date_format(DF("timestamp"),"HH:mm:ss").between("01:00:00","01:10:00"),"InTime").otherwise("NotInTime"))
```

`attendenceDF.show()`

`+--------------------+---------------+------+-----------+
 |           timestamp| login         | Age  | Attendence|
 +--------------------+---------------+------+-----------+
 2016-06-01 01:05:20  |        7372   |    50|InTime     |
 2016-06-01 01:00:20  |        7374   |    35|InTime     |
 2016-06-01 01:10:20  |        7376   |    40|NotInTime  |`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the functions `hour` and `minute` of the [functions package](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val tsCol = col("timestamp").cast(TimestampType)

val filteredDF = df.filter(
  (hour(tsCol) === 1) && (minute(tsCol).between(0, 10))
)
```

Answer (score -1):

if the timestamp is of type string then with a substring you could do it.

if it is of type unix then you coould convert it, but more efficient is to look in the exact library and format of the type it is saved and check to a way to extract the hour and minute.

hope it helps you :)